# Not submitting build tasks when starting Cassandra

Tags: java

I am using Cassandra 3.10 on a Mac running Java 8, with a simple single node install Cassandra starts but I get the following error:
ViewManager.java:137 - Not submitting build tasks for views in keyspace system_schema as storage service is not initialized
and
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cache schema version aebfa107-efe7-347c-8bf8-a9810b9a3e6f does not match current schema version 80cf8b78-b3c9-3470-a4cf-64d75a70d784.
I have created my own keySpace with approx 200 tables. it seems to start ok and cqlsh works

Comment: Do you have run some migration process changing the shape of tables?

Comment: There are no processes running, I did a clean install of Cassandra and using the DBeaver client I created the tables as simple : create table (....) statements.